# How to make jest fake timers work with asynchronous functions in jest/react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, usefaketimers

```
test('user is logged out when the server doesnt resond with a new access token', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(storageUtils, "getItemAndCheckExpiry")
    spy.mockImplementation(() => {return JSON.stringify({access: 'efrijreoireor', refresh: 'rufrijfreijriej'})})
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    history.push('/auth')
    render(
        <Router history={history}>
        <AuthProvider >
            
            <App />
        
        </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
    )
    await waitFor(() => expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/'))
    expect(screen.getByText(/Something went wrong/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(6000)
    expect(screen.queryByText(/Something went wrong/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    
    // expect(timeOut).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    // expect(timeOut).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 4000);
    spy.mockRestore()
```

What this test should do is make sure that the message "something went wrong" disappears after 5 seconds. However, it doesn't work. I believe it is because I use fake timers inside an async function, but don't know how to solve this problem.

```
    }catch(err){
        logout(); 
        setUnexpectedLogoutError('Something went wrong and you were logged out.')
        setTimeout(() => {
            setUnexpectedLogoutError(null)
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

That's how this functionality is implemented. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to set `useFakeTimers()` before the test in `beforeAll` or `beforeEach`, but leave `advanceTimersByTime` when it is.

Comment: @VladislavSorokin, unfortunately, now neither of my tests in this file work (all are async).

Comment: well, you have a lot of actions in your test. What I would do first is to extract mocking and all jest methods out of the `test()`, check jest docs – they showcasing it

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Jest uses the Sinon project's fake-timers library under the hood. This library has had the option of asynchronously ticking timers for years, but it was only on [March 6 this year (2023)](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/13435) that Jest *exposed* the async API in release 29.5!

So if you wanted to do this in January 2022, you would either have had to use [Sinon's fake timers API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinonjs/fake-timers) or another approach that would flush the pending tasks on the event loop (the async bits). Not that using `@sinonjs/fake-timers` is such a bad idea: I think that API is clearer to use and you get the latest features immediately, but I am hardly neutral, having maintained it for years, along with Simen Bekkhus of Jest fame and others :)

The 29.5 release added these methods:

```
advanceTimersToNextTimerAsync (nextAsync)
runAllTimersAsync (runAllAsync)
runOnlyPendingTimersAsync (runToLastAsync)
advanceTimersByTimeAsync(msToRun) (tickAsync(time))
```

You can probably solve your issue using the last one, just doing:

```
await jest.advanceTimersByTimeAsync(6000)
```

> This just calls out to [fake-timers' tickAsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinonjs/fake-timers#user-content-clockticktime--await-clocktickasynctime) under the hood

It's hard to be 100% certain, of course, without a fully reproducible snippet of code, though, but you can see me doing similar things [in this test](https://github.com/fatso83/retry-dynamic-import/blob/e0204a4/lib/dynamic-import-with-retry.test.ts#L38) where I await the results of an async function that uses `setTimeout` internally.

---

Another approach that tries to flush promises manually can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59243586/200987)). That will work as well, unless you have stubbed out `setImmediate` ...